# Possible to selected item in listView1 is selected in listView2? c#

Tags: c#, listview

Just wondering if it is possible to select the same item in `listView2` like the item in `listView1` is selected? So that the user don't have to select the same item twice. Just for usability :) I'm programming in c#

Comment: `listView2.SelectedValue = listView1.SelectedValue;` ?

Comment: There is no `.SelectedValue`

Comment: `SelectedItems`?  `SelectedIndicies`?  There are a handful of different `ListView` objects out there, you should specify which one you're using.

Comment: I tried `listView2.SelectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems;` but it occured an error.

Comment: @rschweri: that's because it doesn't just return a string. Put some effort in it and edit your post once you have some concrete attempt to show. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx

Comment: @JeroenVannevel thank you, the link helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle `ItemSelectedChanged` of ListView1`

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (int item in listView1.SelectedIndices)
   {
       if (listView1.Items[item].Selected)
       {
           listView2.Items[item].Selected = true;
           tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
           listView2.Select();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Won't work :/ But thanks for code. Maybe I now know where I can start :)

Comment: @rschweri Are you sure. i tried it before posting. Whats the problem do you have an error??

Comment: There isn't an error. I select an item and then I click a button which move me to another `tabPage` and then the same item should be selected. I cloned the items from tab1 to tab2 like this:

`listViewKundenWerkstatt.Items.Add((ListViewItem)lvitem.Clone());`

Comment: Mh, now when I select an item, it directly switch to tabPage2. So I can't select it, and click a button.

Comment: @rschweri Then place evenhandler in `button_click`

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much! I would do +1 but i don't have 15 reputation >.< Have a nice evening :)

Comment: @rschweri Glas i could hellp